# Infinite scroll causing random number 1 to print before actual data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

I am able to get the scroll itself to work, I have it to load the next 5 items on scroll, however before those next 5 appear a number 1 is inserted above the results and this keeps repeating until the end. Once the end is reached the scroll continues to print number 1 as if it were stuck in a loop of scrolling.

Another odd point to note is that if you scroll too fast the records duplicate as if the query is run twice.

**scroll.php** code below:

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="post-data">
    <?php
        require('config.php');

            $sql = "SELECT postID, postTitle, postDesc FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID DESC LIMIT 5"; 
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
    ?>

    <?php include('data.php'); ?>

</div>

<div class="ajax-load text-center" style="display:none">
   <p><img src="loader.gif"> Loading More post</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).scroll(function() {
       if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
           var last_id = $(".post-id:last").attr("id");
           loadMoreData(last_id);
       }
   });

   function loadMoreData(last_id){
     $.ajax(
           {
               url: '/loadMoreData.php?last_id=' + last_id,
               type: "get",
               beforeSend: function()
               {
                   $('.ajax-load').show();
               }
           })
           .done(function(data)
           {
                   $('.ajax-load').hide();
                   $("#post-data").append(data);
           })
           .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
           {
                 alert('server not responding...');
           });
   }
</script>
```

**data.php** code below:

```
<?php
   while($post = $result->fetch_assoc()){
?>
<div class="post-id" id="<?php echo $post['postID']; ?>">

   <h3><a href=""><?php echo $post['postTitle']; ?></a></h3>
   <p><?php echo $post['postDesc']; ?></p>

   <div class="text-right">

       <button class="btn btn-success">Read More</button>

   </div>

   <hr style="margin-top:5px;">

</div>
<?php
  }
?>
```

**loadMoreData.php** code below:

```
<?php
   require('config.php');

   $sql = "SELECT postID, postTitle, postDesc FROM blog_posts
     WHERE postID < '".$_GET['last_id']."' ORDER BY postID DESC LIMIT 5"; 

   $result = $conn->query($sql);

   $json = include('data.php');

   echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change **loadMoreData.php** as bwlow. Remove `echo json_encode($json);` from last

```
<?php
   require('config.php');

   $sql = "SELECT postID, postTitle, postDesc FROM blog_posts
     WHERE postID < '".$_GET['last_id']."' ORDER BY postID DESC LIMIT 5"; 

   $result = $conn->query($sql);

   include('data.php');

?>
```

**Update**

For stop scrolling until last ajax call complete. You can Use flag variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   loaded = true; //<-----Initialize
   $(window).scroll(function() {
       if(($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) && loaded) { //<-----Add in condition
           var last_id = $(".post-id:last").attr("id");
           loadMoreData(last_id);
       }
   });

   function loadMoreData(last_id){
     loaded = false; //<----- change it to false as soon as start ajax call
     $.ajax(
           {
               url: '/loadMoreData.php?last_id=' + last_id,
               type: "get",
               beforeSend: function()
               {
                   $('.ajax-load').show();
               }
           })
           .done(function(data)
           {
                   $('.ajax-load').hide();
                   $("#post-data").append(data);
                   loaded  = true; //<--- again change it to true
           })
           .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
           {
                 alert('server not responding...');
                 loaded  = true;
           });
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Jheez it was as simple as that! Thanks man... Any clues on how to stop the scroll going crazy after the final item is loaded? I.e right at the bottom of the page